# FireStore How to do ClientSideJoin

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

users and posts are in separate Refs.

What I want to do is below.

First get post from postsRef, get the corresponding user in usersRef by using post.ownerID, put both in the tuple. Repeat this.

```
// 1, Get Posts
// 2, Get Post's Owner by using ownerID of the Post
// 3, Add (Post, User) to Joined Posts
// 4, Repeat 1,2,3
func getPostsByNew(onSuccess: @escaping ([(Post, User)]) -> Void) {
    postsRef.order(by: timestamp_field, descending: false).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if let _ = error { return }
        var joinedPosts: [(post: Post, user: User)] = []
        guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return }
        for document in documents {
            let post = Post(dict: document.data(), key: document.documentID)
            print("ownerID: ", post.ownerID)  // "user_1(ownerID)"
            API.User.getUser(userID: post.ownerID!, completion: { (user) in
            print("userID: ", user.userID)  // "user_1(userID)"
                joinedPosts.append((post: post, user: user))
            })
        }
        print(joinedPosts.count)  // 0
        onSuccess(joinedPosts)
    }
}
```

For `print("ownerID:", post.ownerID)` and `print("userID:", user.userID)` in the for statement, normal number of IDs was displayed.
But why is `print(joinedPosts.count)` displayed as `0`?

I thought that the closure's asynchronous processing was the cause, but I do not know how to fix it. Please help me. I will supplement as soon as there is a missing place

Comment: For future readers: to save some time, the code in the question isn't too far off. The main issue is the function *API.User.getUser* is getting user info asynchronously and doesn't complete that task until after the *print(joinedPosts.count)* is called, therefore the array is 0 when the print function is called and populated after. My (really long) answer provides one solution.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: The question is for FireStore so this answer includes a Firebase Database answer as well as a Firestore answer and then a complete Firestore answer.

**Firebase Database**
The question is how to iterate over the posts node and get the user that's associated with each post via the users uid.

Here you go

Given a structure

```
posts
  post_0
    post: "some post"
    uid: "uid_1"
  post_1
    post: "another post"
    uid: "uid_1"
users
  uid_0
    Name: "Henry"
  uid_1
    Name: "Josh"
```

and the code to iterate over all posts and print the post and the user name that created it:

```
let postsRef = self.ref.child("posts")
let usersRef = self.ref.child("users")
postsRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    guard let allPostsSnapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {return}
    for childPostSnap in allPostsSnapshot {
        let uid = childPostSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "uid").value as! String
        let post = childPostSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "post").value as! String
        let thisUserRef = usersRef.child(uid)
        thisUserRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { userSnap in
            let userName = userSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "Name").value as! String
            print(post, userName)
        })
    }
})
```

and the output

```
some post  Josh
another post  Josh
```

**FireStore**

I broke this into two functions, one to read the posts documents and one to read the user name for each post. I am just printing strings in this answer but this shows how to acces the FireStore data so you can extrapolate from there.

```
func readPosts() {
   self.db.collection("posts").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
       if let err = err {
           print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
       } else {
           for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
               let uid = document.get("uid") as! String
               let post = document.get("post") as! String
               self.printUserAndPost(withUid: uid, andPost: post)
           }
       }
   }
}

func printUserAndPost(withUid: String, andPost: String) {
   let docRef = self.db.collection("users").document(withUid)
   docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
       if let document = document, document.exists {
           let name = document.get("name") as! String
           print(name, andPost)
       } else {
           print("doument does not exist")
       }
   }
}
```

and the output

```
Josh Some Post
Josh Another post
```

**Another Edit:**

Based on comments from the original poster, they would like to add a post object and user object to and array as a tuple. Since we don't have that information in the original post, I've crafted a pretty complete solution - see below. The second question is why is the tuple array printing a count of 0 in the original post. The reason is that Firebase / Firestore is asynchronous and in the original question, this line

```
print(joinedPosts.count)
```

is being called *before* the users are populated from

```
API.User.getUser(userID: post.ownerID!
```

so the array is in fact 0 when that function is called and is > 0 at some point in time afterwards. My answer includes handling that.

```
class PostClass {
    var post_id = ""
    var post_text = ""
    var owner_id = ""
    init(ownerId: String, postId: String, postText: String) {
        self.owner_id = ownerId
        self.post_id = postId
        self.post_text = postText
    }
}

class UserClass {
    var user_id = ""
    var user_name = ""
    init(userId: String, userName: String) {
        self.user_id = userId
        self.user_name = userName
    }
}

var joinedPosts = [(aUser: UserClass, aPost: PostClass)]()
var docCount = 0

func readPosts() {
    self.db.collection("posts").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            self.docCount = querySnapshot!.documents.count

            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                let postId = document.documentID
                let uid = document.get("uid") as! String
                let postText = document.get("post") as! String
                let post = PostClass(ownerId: uid, postId: postId, postText: postText)
                self.addUserAndPostTupleToArray(withUid: uid, andPost: post)
            }
        }
    }
}

func addUserAndPostTupleToArray(withUid: String, andPost: PostClass) {
    let docRef = self.db.collection("users").document(withUid)
    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            let name = document.get("name") as! String
            let user = UserClass(userId: withUid, userName: name)
            let myTuple = (aUser: user, aPost: andPost)
            self.joinedPosts.append(myTuple)

            if self.joinedPosts.count == self.docCount {
                print("total posts: \(self.joinedPosts.count)")
                for myTuple in self.joinedPosts {
                   let name = myTuple.aUser.user_name
                   let postText = myTuple.aPost.post_text
                   print("User \(name) said \(postText)")
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("doument does not exist")
        }
    }
}
```

and the output is

```
total posts: 2
User Josh said Some Post
User Josh said Another post
```

Comment: Thank you for answering!
But, this looks like RealtimeDatabase, what happens when you write in FireStore?

Comment: I am glad if you can see the question changed a bit more.

Comment: @son My apologies, I overlooked that you were asking about FireStore. I have updated the answer to reflect both a Firebase Database solution as well as a FireStore solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind response!
But I want to initialize Post and User and return it as an array of tuples.
And for the future as well why when I execute my code, ```print("ownerID:", post.ownerID)``` and ```print("userID:", user.userID)``` are displayed for the number, but the last print It is necessary to know the reason why ```print(joinedPosts.count)``` will be ```0```. Since I write comments using the translation site, there may be places you do not understand the meaning, but please let me know if there is one

Comment: @son I understand and have updated my answer to address your questions and provide a complete code example.